# Specify different style of each table

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, css

I'm generating tables based on some fields from database and I need to specify different style for each table. How could specify different style for each table.

This is my code

```
<table width="100%">
  <% @content_data['personnel_cv_data_types'].each do |personnel_cv_data_type| %>
 <tr width="100%">
 <td>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>
    <table style="font-size:13px;"width="100%" class="personnel_cvdata_view_table_first_row">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= @content_data['lable_title_'+personnel_cv_data_type] %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a onClick="add_new_entry('<%= personnel_cv_data_type %>')">Add&nbsp;<%= @content_data['lable_add_'+personnel_cv_data_type] %></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </legend>
```

Here each table takes the same style as **personnel_cvdata_view_table_first_row**, How could generate tables with different style class for example

```
  class="personnel_cvdata_view_table_first_row_1"
  class=""ersonnel_cvdata_view_table_first_row_2
```

and so on an  and i can write separate style for each table

Comment: Do you want alternating/'zebra' classes? Or just unique numbers assigned to them? Or the records' IDs? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry no alternative I need different style for each table , because the fields form db is varying length(name,education qualification, work experience) so I want organize them in good format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
<% @content_data['personnel_cv_data_types'].each do |personnel_cv_data_type| %>
```

Use

```
<% @content_data['personnel_cv_data_types'].each.with_index do |personnel_cv_data_type, counter| %>
```

And then you can create your tables like this

```
<table style="font-size:13px;"width="100%" class="personnel_cvdata_view_table_first_row_<%= counter %>">
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this seems to fit your needs:

```
<% @content_data['personnel_cv_data_types'].each_with_index do |personnel_cv_data_type, index| %>
...
<table style="font-size:13px;"width="100%" class="personnel_cvdata_view_table_first_row_<%= index + 1 %>">
```

Comment: You guys are awesome...Thanks.I've gave the tick to other guys he don't have much reputation.sorry!

Comment: I like the spread of the points.  Upvote to apneadiving for a) having a cool name and b) being a good sport.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class based on some unique identifier, possibly even the string personnel_cv_data_type itself if it is unique.

```
<table style="font-size:13px;"width="100%" class="#{personnel_cv_data_type}">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= @content_data['lable_title_'+personnel_cv_data_type] %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a onClick="add_new_entry('<%= personnel_cv_data_type %>')">Add&nbsp;<%= @content_data['lable_add_'+personnel_cv_data_type] %></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I don't know specifically what you want to make different about each style, but if the list is determinate, you could set up styles for each of the above types.